# Discord not loading slash commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a slash command system for my discord.js bot, but it does not show up in the app

Here is the code I am using

```js
const {
    Client,
    Collection,
    Intents
} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]
});
const fs = require('fs');

const {
    Routes
} = require('discord-api-types/v9');

const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const commands = [];

// Creating a collection for commands in client
client.commands = new Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        // Set a new item in the Collection
        // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
        console.log(`Loaded slash command /${command.data.name}.`)
    }


    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;
    const rest = new REST({
        version: '9'
    }).setToken("myToken");
    (async () => {
        try {

            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), {
                    body: commands
                },
            );
            console.log('Successfully registered all application commands globally');

        } catch (error) {
            if (error) console.error(error);
        }
    })();
})

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    const { options } = interaction

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction, options, client);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({
            content: `ERROR: There was a problem executing the **${command.name}** command. Please try again later.`,
            ephemeral: true
        });
    }
});

client.login("myToken")
```

This is my command file (My ping.js file)

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Ping Pong!"),
    async execute(interaction, options, client) {
        interaction.reply("Pong!")
    }
}
```

Whenever I launch my bot, no slash commands appear. All the strings are logged to the console though.

I have given the bot application.commands scope.

Comment: "Global commands are cached for one hour. New global commands will fan out slowly across all guilds and will only be guaranteed to be updated after an hour. Guild commands update instantly. As such, we recommend you use guild-based commands during development and publish them to global commands when they're ready for public use." - [Registering slash commands](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#global-commands)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have done that and my problem has been fixed.